# nagios nrpe check_procs wrong return value

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios, nrpe

I have a problem with my nagios monitoring. I'm trying to check a process on a remote host using nrpe.

The host was already been monitored by nagios, so I only needed to add a line to the nrpe.cfg file. There was even already a check_procs check defined so I could use that example.

So simple you might thick but no. I check if I could run the command manually and no problems there!

```
ubuntu@host:/usr/lib/nagios/plugins$ ./check_procs -w 1:1 -c 1:1 -a delayed_job
PROCS OK: 1 process with args 'delayed_job'
ubuntu@host:/usr/lib/nagios/plugins$ sudo ./check_procs -w 1:1 -c 1:1 -a delayed_job
PROCS OK: 1 process with args 'delayed_job'
```

This is a piece my nrpe.cfg file:

```
command[check_procs]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -s $ARG3$
command[check_proc_name]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -a $ARG3$
```

The first check check_procs is being monitored correctly, the last line was mine I added but responds with this : **PROCS CRITICAL: 2 processes with args 'delayed_job'**

This is my service file :

```
define service {
  use                 generic-service
  host_name           imobiel.limburger.nl
  service_description Check Delayed Job Proces
  check_command       check_nrpe!check_proc_name!1:1 1:1 delayed_job
}
```

Anybody an idea ? I restarted nagios server and the nrpe server several times already!
Hopefully someone expienced the same issues?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I changed the configuration a little bit like this:
    command[check_proc_name]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -w 1:1 -c 1:1 -a delayed_job
 and removed the parameters from the check_nrpe command, now nagios returns status: unkown. Saying it didn't received a response from nrpe will the other nrpe checks on the server are fine! Anybody know another approach?

Comment: Is the remote system a Solaris box, by chance?

Comment: No sorry it's a debian based distro

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a bug in check_procs: it seems to pick up itself when running from nrpe, as opposed to the command line.  Maybe a race condition of some sort.

I see you're running Ubuntu, given your command prompt.  With the check_procs available on Lucid, I'm able to do something like:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs --ereg-argument-array="[s]tring" -w 1:1
```

So, we'll do a pattern match on the argument list, but in such a way that the check_procs process won't be matched.  Putting one character of the pattern into square brackets causes the expression to match on "string" but it obviously won't match on the check_procs argument "[s]tring".

The check_procs available on Hardy doesn't have the regex option, though.

Comment: This is absolutely not a bug in check_procs; if you look at the source, and find the line under "Ignore self", you can see that it explicitly... ignores itself.

Comment: Yes, I see the source and I see the "Ignore self" section.  And yet, with version 1.4.14, I see the same behavior the OP is seeing: when running check_procs directly, it's correct in seeing 1 proc, but if it's run via nrpe it finds 2 procs.  And I haven't duplicated checks in my nrpe configs, like the OP has done.

Comment: @cjc Do you have the same problem as me then? Did you found some answers?

Comment: @user1132127, my solution was to use the --ereg-argument-array as I have above, basically use the pattern like described in, say, this: http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/03/trick-grep-not-to-report-itself-in.html

Comment: Same bug on check_procs v1.4.15 (nagios-plugins 1.4.15). Works with --ereg-argument-array.

Answer (score 3):

There is problem with a /bin/ps output on host. By default, "check_procs" binary do a "/bin/ps -axwo" on checked system, which cut arg string.
Just recompile nagios-plugins from source. On version 1.4.15 must set configure options:

```
./configure --enable-extra-opts=yes --with-ps-command="/bin/ps -axwwo 'stat uid pid ppid vsz rss pcpu ucomm command'" --with-ps-format="%s %d %d %d %d %d %f %s %n" --with-ps-cols=9 --with-ps-varlist="procstat,&procuid,&procpid,&procppid,&procvsz,&procrss,&procpcpu,procprog,&pos"
```

When we set -axWWo - ps get us full string of arguments.
Sorry for my ingreesh.

Answer (score 0):

What version of nagios-plugins do you have? check_procs in 1.4.15 does not exhibit this behavior. I have not checked earlier versions, though.

Add "-vv" or "-vvv" to the end of your manual test, and you can verify exactly what 'ps' command it is running, what it is seeing, and what it considers matching.

If you're **actually** having Nagios run both "check_procs" and "check_proc_name" as they are defined in your nrpe.cfg snippet, at the same time, with the same exact args... then it's quite possible that **they would pick up each other** in the count. But why would you be running two checks that do exactly the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I actually had this problem too, for me defining the user worked. For instance -u root. since the NRPE server runs it's check as the Nagios user, specifically calling out the user avoids this problem.